# Notification problem on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, notification

I recently installed `i3-gaps` on my Xubuntu machine, and noticed that my notifications did not look the same as they used to when I logged back on Xfce. Switching the notification style in the notification settings did not change anything, and remained like this:

[image]

Is there anyway this can be fixed without having to reinstall i3-gaps?

Comment: Did you try purging `i3-gaps` again? This way you could verify this package is responsible for the change.

Comment: @dessert I've never purged i3-gaps before, which I was hoping to avoid because I've already invested a bit in customizing it. I guess I'll edit my question to allow for solutions to remove Xfce instead.

Comment: OK, how about just removing it using `apt remove`? This way you will keep all your configuration and still be able to test whether it's the package's fault.

Comment: @dessert sorry for being away, I ran apt remove and said i3 is not installed, so not removed, despite it being on my computer, so I decided to purge instead.

Comment: Ran purge, and the notifications have not been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it was the *~/.xsession* file missing. To fix that, create or modify the file as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

dunst & \
startxfce4
```

[source](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11382)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I think i3 package for Ubuntu installs dunst notification daemon and it's to be blamed here.

Removing it and starting xfce4-notifyd service worked for me.